# How to change current working directory in Lean 4?

Tags: lean

In Lean 4, we have `IO.currentDir` which returns the cwd.  Is it possible to set the cwd though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No

**Long answer:** Yes, but probably not in a nice way that you would ever want to use in practice.

If you dig into the [IO source](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/master/src/Init/System/IO.lean), you will see `IO.currentDir` is defined as an opaque reference to the underlying [`lean_io_current_dir`](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/a4226a4f6d266ede66ea8ee7c4ad31fb10da1e4a/src/runtime/io.cpp#L867). If we look at `lean_io_current_dir` we see it just queries the C function [`getcwd`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html).
`getcwd` has no problem getting a new path as long as we can tell the OS to set it somehow. Doing this in Lean4 is the hard part since we need to somehow call [`chdir`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) on ourselves, and to my knowledge the Lean developers have not given us a nice way to do this. However, something like this can be implemented in a hacky system dependent way. The following is an example of a hacky Linux solution based on [gdb](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) I've gotten to work. This solution is based off [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281994/changing-the-current-working-directory-of-a-certain-process).

```
def chdir (newdir : System.FilePath) : IO UInt32 := do
  let PID <- IO.Process.getPID
  let cmd :=
    "gdb -q <<EOF\nattach " ++ toString PID ++
    "\ncall (int) chdir(\"" ++ newdir.toString ++
    "\")\ndetach\nquit\nEOF"
  let proc <- IO.Process.spawn {
    cmd := "bash"
    args := #["-c", cmd]
    stdout := IO.Process.Stdio.null
    stderr := IO.Process.Stdio.null
  }
  IO.Process.Child.wait proc

def main : IO Unit := do
  let cwd <- IO.currentDir
  IO.println cwd
  IO.FS.createDir "subdir"
  let _ <- chdir "subdir"
  --We are now in subdir
  let cwd <- IO.currentDir
  IO.println cwd
  let _ <- chdir ".."
  --We are now back in the starting directory
  let cwd <- IO.currentDir
  IO.println cwd
  IO.FS.removeDir "subdir"
```

The solution works by using gdb to attach to the main lean process via its PID and forcing it to run the `chdir` syscall.

Comment: Perhaps I will open a feature request.